# Make the table cells stay the same width

Tags: html, css, html-table, width, cell

I'm trying to find a way in which my cell's width doesn't change after I type the text but rather that the text short itself or that the text can get the whole cell without the table becoming larger.

```
    <td>
    <a href="http://www.google.com/">Cell 2</a>
  </td>

  <td>
    <a href="http://www.google.com/">Cell 2</a>
  </td>
```

[image: Table cell]

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/eV869/)

Comment: How is the cell width set now, what does “the text short itself” or “the text can get the whole cell” mean, and what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

Add `table-layout:fixed` to the table.

```
.datagrid table{
    table-layout:fixed;
}
```

[**Updated fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/eV869/1/)